# How to clear the Search History from the Autocomplete Textbox in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

This is how i am binding the Autocomplete Textbox:-

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,5,0,0" Name="autoCompleteBox" ItemsSource="{Binding List,Mode=TwoWay}" ValueMemberPath="Details" FilterMode="Contains" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" SelectedItem="{Binding Path= SelectedFromList,Mode=TwoWay
                                <sdk:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </sdk:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </sdk:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Problem is i am not able to Clear the previously searched data from the Autocompletetext box, and every time i search it show all the records that i searched previously.

Can anybody suggest how to clear previous records??

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141529/sl4-autocompletebox-repeating-filter-results-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know how to do this in ViewModel but in code behind in the event "Populating"
clear the selectedItem and Itemsource and bind it again and it will work,

```
    var items = this.autoCompleteBoxSingle.ItemsSource;
    this.autoCompleteBoxSingle.ItemsSource = null;
    this.autoCompleteBoxSingle.SelectedItem = null;
    this.autoCompleteBoxSingle.ItemsSource = items;
```