# AutoCompleteBox (Silverlight 4) displays previously selected items in dropdown list

Tags: silverlight-4.0, autocompletebox

I intended to use a AutoCompleteBox (silverlight 4) in similar way like a save file dialog works: each time user types a string, only matching items are displayed in dropdown list.

However, this is not the behavior I get from  AutoCompleteBox. I will describe the bahavior by example: in my case, I have collection with two strings: "xxx" and "yyy". The AutoCompleteBox is bound to that collection. User start typing "xxx". The dropdown list correctly displays "xxx". User selects "xxx" from the list. User deletes "xxx", and instead of it types "yyy". The dropdown list displays both "xxx" and "yyy".

What I tried to do:
1. Tried to play with FilterMode. If I using "None" mode, both items always being displayed. Any other mode provides the behavior described above.
2. Tried to set my own filtering predicate, by binding to Filter property on the model. In addition, set the FilterMode to "Custom". Any attempt to type inside AutoCompleteBox crashes the application.

I will really appreciate any help, burn on this already two hours..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same error and for me it was caused by the styling of the `ListBoxItem`.  Use the default styling and the problem should go away.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5529940/2568763